# SQL Server migration to mySQL, tips & potential issues?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, open-source

I'm looking into whether a move from SQL Server is a viable option. To help me with this decision, I have some questions:

**Is it possible to use asp.net membership on a MySQL server ?**

Are there many/any useful tools to migrate tables/databases/etc and which ones are the best?

What are the Main disadvantages in moving to MySQL from SQL Server?

As it stands I have a large enough project but it doesn't avail of many MS features so if it's possible I'd like to move.

Comment: If cost is your concern, have you considered the (free) Express Edition of Sql Server? The only limitations are supported RAM and a 10GB database size.

Comment: The real question is why do you want to move the data? In any event data conversion is a risky proposition that opens you  to the possibility of new bugs. It should only bee done if needed not because someone would prefer to use a different database.  Conversion is a time-consuming process as well, typically a conversion project will run 3-6 months some even up to a year.

Answer (score 1):

My company did this a couple years ago with a pretty big project.  On thing that made it easier for us is that we mostly used very plain standards compliant SQL.  No Linq, no Entity Framework, only a little T-SQL, and only a few stored procedures.

As far as getting your data into MySQL, We ended up creating our own tool for doing this.  None of the existing stuff including "MySQL Migration Assistant" can anywhere close to being fully functional.  Once you can recreate the schema on MySQL, Getting the data back in, is a matter of exporting to CSV and importing with [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).  Tranferring the schema was actually the hardest part.  With so many tables, we couldn't just do it by hand.  We wrote some code in .Net by starting off using [this VBScript](http://kofler.info/english/mssql2mysql/) that we found, and upgraded it to use the tools in "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management" Namespace available for .Net.

For functions that exist in SQL Server but don't exist in MySQL, such as GetDate, it's easy enough to write your own functions in MySQL that map to these functions, instead of trying to find all the instances of this stuff in the code.  There are quite a few syntax differences between MySQL and SQL Server, even with just using basic SQL.  For instance MSSQL allows DELETE TABLENAME WHERE ...., but MySQL insists you use DELETE FROM TABLENAME WHERE.....  That's just one, there are many other differences.

Anyway, it was quite an adventure, but it worked out well for us.  It is do-able, but you have to be committed, and not be afraid to write your own migration tools.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things off the top of my head.

MySQL doesn't support CHECK constraints. Usually, if your dbms *does* support CHECK constraints, your tables use them.

Depending on the constraint, you might be able to rewrite it in one of these ways.

- As a foreign key to a new table
- As a trigger
- As a daily (or hourly, whatever) exception report
- As a module in application code (which *could* be part of an exception report)
- Something else I haven't thought of.

MySQL's timestamps have a resolution of one second.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a SQL Server Migration Assistant but, naturally, it is designed to help users move in the other direction.

You may want to check out this whitepaper from the MySQL site (you'll need to register - I did not, so I don't know how valuable the paper will be compared to the knowledge you already possess):

http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql_wp_mssql2mysql.php

There are also some products and guides that can be found with a fairly simple search, e.g.

http://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/tutorials/convert-mssql-sql-server-to-mysql.php

http://www.haidongji.com/2009/02/23/moving-data-from-sql-server-to-mysql/

I don't know that the ASP.NET Membership can be ported directly to MySQL but I am confident you could replicate its functionality (it is more a question of how much effort it will take, not whether or not it is possible).

Comment: Right, vendors don't help to move *away* from their products.  Heh :-)

Comment: SSIS can be used to send data to mysql but it has a pretty steep learning lcurve.